# I'd like to know how to print all the FormView screens

Tags: c++, printing, mfc, formview

I added Formview screen to Dialog and dynamically added controls to Formview screen. With more control, scrolling appeared on the Formview screen. In this situation, when I try to output the Formview screen to the printer, only the truncated screen that has not been scrolled is visible.
[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASqSm.png)

How can I modify it to get all the scrolled screens?This is the code I wrote to output the Formview screen.

```
void DIReportView::OnPrepareDC(CDC* pDC, CPrintInfo* pInfo)
{
    // TODO: Add your specialized code here and/or call the base class
    if (pInfo)
    {
        CClientDC dc(this);
        pDC->SetMapMode(MM_ANISOTROPIC);

        CSize sz(dc.GetDeviceCaps(LOGPIXELSX), dc.GetDeviceCaps(LOGPIXELSY));
        pDC->SetWindowExt(sz);
        sz = CSize(pDC->GetDeviceCaps(LOGPIXELSX), pDC->GetDeviceCaps(LOGPIXELSY));
        pDC->SetViewportExt(sz);
    }
}

BOOL DIReportView::OnPreparePrinting(CPrintInfo* pInfo)
{
    pInfo->SetMaxPage(1);

    pInfo->m_pPD->m_pd.Flags &= ~PD_NOSELECTION;
    pInfo->m_pPD->m_pd.hInstance = AfxGetInstanceHandle();

    // default preparation
    return DoPreparePrinting(pInfo);
}

void DIReportView::OnBeginPrinting(CDC* pDC, CPrintInfo* pInfo)
{
    
}

void DIReportView::OnEndPrinting(CDC* pDC, CPrintInfo* pInfo)
{
}

void DIReportView::OnPrint(CDC* pDC, CPrintInfo* pInfo)
{
    if (pInfo == NULL)
        return;

    if (m_dib.GetHandle() == NULL)
        return;
    {
        GLock lock(m_dib);
        BITMAPINFOHEADER* pBMI = (BITMAPINFOHEADER*)(LPVOID)lock;

        int nColors = 0;
        if (pBMI->biBitCount <= 8)
            nColors = (1 << pBMI->biBitCount);

        ::StretchDIBits(pDC->GetSafeHdc(),
            pInfo->m_rectDraw.left,
            pInfo->m_rectDraw.top,
            pBMI->biWidth,
            pBMI->biHeight,
            0,
            0,
            pBMI->biWidth,
            pBMI->biHeight,
            (LPBYTE)pBMI + (pBMI->biSize + nColors * sizeof(RGBQUAD)),
            (BITMAPINFO*)pBMI,
            DIB_RGB_COLORS,
            SRCCOPY);
    }
    //pDC->SetMapMode(MM_ANISOTROPIC);
    //pDC->SetWindowExt(m_pMemDC->GetDeviceCaps(LOGPIXELSX), m_pMemDC->GetDeviceCaps(LOGPIXELSY));
    //pDC->SetViewportExt(pDC->GetDeviceCaps(LOGPIXELSX), pDC->GetDeviceCaps(LOGPIXELSY));
    //pDC->StretchBlt(0, 0, m_rect.Width(), m_rect.Height(), m_pMemDC, 0, 0, m_rect.Width(), m_rect.Height(), SRCCOPY);

}

void DIReportView::OnFilePrintPreview()
{
    _grapImage();
    CFormView::OnFilePrintPreview();
}

void DIReportView::OnFilePrint()
{
    _grapImage();
    CFormView::OnFilePrint();
    
}

void DIReportView::_grapImage()
{
    //Grap Image
    CPoint oldPoint = GetScrollPosition();
    CPoint pt(0, 0);//scroll to up
    this->ScrollToPosition(pt);
    
    CClientDC dc(this);
    CRect rect;
    this->GetClientRect(rect);
    
    m_dib.Attach(GDIUtil::GrabDIB(&dc, rect));

    ScrollToPosition(oldPoint);
}
```

Comment: You will have an `OnPrint` event handler too which accepts some parameters to tell you want page it wants to print. Then you must manually do your drawing and rendering into that printer device context. Do you have such a handler?

Comment: You are taking screen shots. It is no surprise then that what you wind up with is only the part that's actually visible on screen. This isn't only costly, it's also completely unnecessary, and produces low-quality printouts. After all, you're subscribing to the screen's DPI when taking the screenshot, leaving the much higher DPI of your printer unused. [Printing and Print Preview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/printing-and-print-preview) explains how the system is intended to be used.